# How can I reliably use Applescrpt to insert an image in a cell?

Tags: excel, image, applescript, new-operator

I've seen a few posts on this subject. The problem I'm running into is that the script works. Sometimes. It'll work once and then give me the error message:

> Microsoft Excel got an error: Can't make or move that element into that container.

Here's the code:

```
set Image_Folder to alias "Seagate SSD Boot Drive:Users:davidlivingstonssd:Desktop:Photos 800 Temp:"

tell application "Finder"
    set Images_To_Process to files of Image_Folder
    set ImageFile to the first item of Images_To_Process as text
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set theRange to active cell
    set theLeft to left position of active cell
    set theTop to (top of active cell)
    tell active sheet
        make new picture at beginning with properties {file name:ImageFile, height:240, width:320, top:theTop, left position:theLeft, placement:placement move}
    end tell
    activate
end tell
```

I've tried a bunch of things and once in awhile, the picture will pop into place. At others, not so much. Am I missing something? Or is this glitch in Excel's implementation of AppleScript?

I'm using Excel for Mac version 16.47 and MacOS Catalina. Also, Script Debugger 7.0.13.

8:20 AM March 21, 2021 Update. Now here's a strange wrinkle. The script will work if the particular picture has been imported before using Excel's "Insert/Picture.../Picture from File" menu item. New pictures, never imported manually, return the error above. Just dragging the JPG file on to the open worksheet from the Finder seems to have the same effect.

Comment: Two thoughts on this… first, it might be an issue with Catalina's security. When you use Insert/Picture…, this satisfies security and allows access to the image — otherwise failure. Second, are there any differences between the properties of successful vs failed images? Try breaking your 'make new' line in two (after 'properties', with first being, `set ab to {file name:…}, and second being `make new… properties ab`. Then add a line `get ab` (last line inside excel tell block). I'm on Sierra and script worked 100%.

Comment: Awesome. I'll try that. Will advise. Thank you. 